# Reference source code for android-support-v13.jar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library, android-source

I'd like Eclipse to reference the source code for `android-support-v13.jar`, both the v13 code and the v4 code that is bundled withe v13 library.

I created a companion file `android-support-v13.jar.properties` with the following content:

```
src=$SDK/extras/android/support/v13/src;$SDK/extras/android/support/v4/src
```

It didn't work. How do I help Eclipse find the full source code?

Comment: You cannot use environment/eclipse variables in the `properties` file AFAIK. Also, why do you think a semicolon list of folders will work? It's been a while since I've used Eclipse, though.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the `$SDK`. Back when I used android-support-v4, I used just a relative path, which worked. So for purposes of this question, consider `$SDK` as a placeholder for the proper path to the SDK. As for the semicolon, it was a guess. The purpose of this question is to learn what actually does work.